# mongoDB Trigger function getting array subdocument in "changeEvent.updateDescription.updatedFields"

Tags: arrays, mongodb, triggers

I am using mongoDB Triggers on their cloud offering to run a function every time a record is added or updated in a specific DB.

the function job is to perform a specific calculation based on the value field under the Evlautation array sub-document.

- Post

  - eval []

    - ID
    - Value

the Trigger and function are working, however, I am having some challenges to read the value field since the  "changeEvent.updateDescription.updatedFields" contains the eval array index:

```
{\"updatedAt\":\"...\",\"eval.2\":{\"ID\":....,\"Value\":...}}"
```

my question is: how can I read the "eval" sub-document regardless of the Index? sometimes the index can be 2, and sometimes it can be any other number.

Thanks